# I need help writing a working ERC 721 contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, erc-721

I have been unable to write a working ERC 721 contract.Can someone help me with a sample ERC 721 contract that works? I have been learning for about a week now and I haven't made much progress.

Comment: If you have a specific problem, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Doesn't Metamask work with ERC721 tokens? Because I was finally  able to  create one, but It only works with earthfiddle and doesn't work with metamask. I cant even add it to MetaMask.

Comment: The reference implementation cited in the ERC-721 standard is https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are number of examples available.

E.g.:

- https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC721
- https://github.com/m0t0k1ch1/ERC721-token-sample

Comment: Here https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721 is the complete reference implementation of the ERC-721 non-fungible token standard for the Ethereum blockchain with examples.